# Is there a working column filter example for PrimeNG Table (p-table) like the demo?

Tags: angular, typescript

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table

shows a working demo but the stackblitz example is not what is running above.  I have multiselect dropdown fitlers working, but location of the dialog and styling are off.  The styling in the stackblitz in the url above is also off.  I am looking for a working code example with sorting and filtering per column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesort-demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo

Comment: This is very helpful.  I appear to have a couple of issues including CSS leakage/clobbering.  Even when I copy code from these links it doesn't render/work correctly in my app.  I have narrowed some of this down to ngx-toastr likely interfering since it likely uses overlays as does the filtering in p-table.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

So one of my issues was that I had the overlay/popup dialog for the filter not displaying in the right place and under other DOM items weirdly.  I finally solved this after examining CSS by ensuring that I had all of these

```
imports: [        
    ...
    ...
    //start: added from example code for p-table
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TableModule,
    CalendarModule,
    SliderModule,
    DialogModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    ContextMenuModule,
    DropdownModule,
    ButtonModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ProgressBarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    //end: added from example code for p-table
```

in my app.module.ts file.  I must have been missing one or two and it didn't render correctly.  There was no warning or compile issue as those imports seem to be needed "under the covers" for p-table when using column filters as overlays.